# how to send data from one grails application to other grails application

Tags: grails, groovy

I have created 2 application in grails both are interconnected, now I need to pass data from one application to other, how can i pass using redirect url

```
redirect(url:'url path')
```

Comment: Does your control gets passed to another application on `redirect` ?

Comment: yep am redirecting from one application to other but i need to pass data how can i pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can pass your data to controller action pretty easily with use of  `params`

Specify the input parameters like below

```
redirect(uri: "url path", params: [content : "your_data"])
```

You can pass more than one parameter just add that map to `params` like below

```
redirect(uri: "url path", params: [content : "your_data", other_content: "some_other_data"])
```

Please modify the key value as per your need.